# Cell assignment of a 2-dimensional Matrix in Python, without numpy

Tags: python, matrix, variable-assignment

Below is my script, which basically creates a zero matrix of 12x8 filled with 0. Then I want to fill it in, one by one. So lets say column 2 row 0 needs to be 5. How do I do that? The example below shows how I did it and the wrong (for my needs) output:

```
list_MatrixRow = []
list_Matrix = [] #Not to be confused by what the book calls, optimal alignment score matrix

int_NumbOfColumns = 12
int_NumbOfRows = 8

for i in range (0, int_NumbOfColumns): # Puts Zeros across the first Row
    list_AlignMatrixRow.append(0)
for i in range (0, int_NumbOfRows):
    list_AlignMatrix.append(list_AlignMatrixRow) 
#add the list in another list to make matrix of Zeros
#-------------------THE ACTUAL PROBLEMATIC PART; ABOVE IS FINE(It Works)------------

list_AlignMatrix[2][0] = 5 
# This is what logically makes sense but here is the output 
# which happens but I don't want (there should be all 0s and 
# only one 5 on the cell [2][0]):

[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thx everyone! I got it. What I was doing was making a list of the same list which all were pointers to the same list. Also thank you for proper way of writing in python. I am new (4 weeks) in to using python. Thanks all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each row points to the same sublist.  This is the result of appending the same sublist repeatedly.  So when you modify one row, you end up modifying the others.

I would do this:

```
ncols = 12
nrows = 8
matrix = [[0] * ncols for i in range(nrows)]
matrix[2][0] = 5
```

`matrix` contains:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

An aside about coding style:  It is poor form in Python to include the type of the object in its name.  I have chosen to rename `int_NumbOfColumns` as `ncols`.  If you need something more descriptive use something like `column_count`.  Generally, mixedCase names are to be avoided, while CamelCase is generally used for class names.  See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more.

**Edit**:  Since you mentioned that you are new to Python, here's a little more explanation.

This is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
matrix = [[0] * ncols for i in range(nrows)]
```

It can also be written as a regular for-loop:

```
matrix = []
for i in range(nrows):
    matrix.append([0] * ncols)
```

Answer (score 5):

Each entry in `list_AlignMatrix` is a reference to *the same object*.  You'll need to create a new [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) instance for each row in your matrix.  Here's an illustration of what's happening:

```
>>> l = [0]
>>> l2 = [l,l,l]
>>> l2
[[0], [0], [0]]
>>> l2[0][0] = 1
>>> l2
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

You can use the [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) function to confirm that each entry in `l2` is a reference to the same object:

```
>>> [id(x) for x in l2]
[161738316, 161738316, 161738316]
```

To make new copies of your row list, you can rewrite your second loop like this:

```
for i in range (0, int_NumbOfRows):
    list_AlignMatrix.append(list(list_AlignMatrixRow))
```

The [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) constructor will create copies of `list_AlignMatrixRow`, as illustrated by the following example:

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> l2 = list(l)
>>> l == l2
True
>>> l is l2
False
```

Answer (score 1):

When you append `list_AlignMatrixRow`, it's just appending a reference to the original list, so there's really a single 1-D list, and every row of your matrix is pointing to it.  To create a new list, you need to actually create a new list:

```
list_AlignMatrix.append(list(list_AlignMatrixRow))
```

Note the call to list, which creates a list by iterating over and copying the elements of list_AlignMatrixRow

Answer (score 1):

to generate such a matrix, in python, you should use list comprihention like this
if you want to produce a row with all 0,

```
>>> import copy
>>> list_MatrixRow=[0 for i in range(12)]
>>> list_MatrixRow
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

ce
then you can create list of list in same way

> > > list_Matrix=[[0 for j in range(12)] for i in range(8)]

now you can edit any elements

```
>>> list_Matrix[0][2]=12345
>>> list_Matrix[0][2]
12345
>>> list_Matrix
[[0, 0, 12345, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

if you want to create matrix containing all column 5, u can use short circuit evaluation on list comprehension

```
>>> list_MatrixRow=[(i==0 and 5 or 0) for i in range(12)]
>>> list_MatrixRow
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list_Matrix=[list_MatrixRow for i in range(8)]
>>> list_MatrixRow
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list_Matrix
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> list_Matrix[0][0]
5
```

Comment: can anyone tell me why negative votes for my answer!! i think it just gives the result what he wants

Comment: You should also provide a short explanation of why you need to do it this way (see the other answers). P.S. not my downvote.

Comment: I don't downvote but I think it's clear why someone did: the OP is trying to *avoid* having every matrix row be the same identical row.  See his note "here is the output which happens but I don't want".  You reuse `list_MatrixRow`, which gets you into the same problem that the OP came across.

Comment: I downvoted, but since I now have a competing answer I have removed the downvote.  I downvoted because the OP wants "only one 5 on the cell [2][0]".  You put the five on *all* the rows.  Second reason for the downvote was this non-idiomatic bit `(i==0 and 5 or 0)`.  Idiomatically, it is `5 if i == 0 else 0`.

Comment: `deepcopy` will do it, but it's slow, requires an import, and is much longer than `matrixrow[:]` or `list(matrixrow)`.  I'll admit that it handles nested cases that those don't, but here the copy needed is shallow.

Comment: for matrix of elementery types, deepcopy is not efficient. but it is more preferable ay when we deal with higher objects

Comment: `deepcopy` is not commonly used in this situation.  A shallow copy is all that is needed.  When we are talking about a list of integers, the most common ways to make that copy are with a list constructor or with a slice.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski what about short circuit evaluation (i==0 and 5 or 0), isn't it faster than "5 if i == 0"

Comment: It's a hack.  I use it for code golf, but not otherwise.  As far as speed goes, some informal testing reveals that `5 if i == 0 else 0` is slightly faster than `(i==0 and 5 or 0)`.