# cmath module yields incorrect result

Tags: python

Here's a piece of code I wrote:

```
import numpy as n
import cmath, math

v=[1,1,1,1,1][(1+0j), (0.30901699437494723+0.9510565162951536j), (-0.8090169943749477+0.5877852522924728j), (-0.8090169943749471-0.5877852522924736j), (0.3090169943749482-0.9510565162951533j)]



M=[[0]*5]*5
w=[0]*5
for a in range(0,5,1):
    for b in range(0,5,1):
        M[a][b]=cmath.exp(-2j*math.pi*a*b/5)

for k in range(0,5,1):
    for i in range(0,5,1):
        w[k]+=M[k][i]*v[i]

print M[0]
```

Here's the output:

```
[(1+0j), (0.30901699437494723+0.9510565162951536j), (-0.8090169943749477+0.5877852522924728j), (-0.8090169943749471-0.5877852522924736j), (0.3090169943749482-0.9510565162951533j)]
```

However, it should be [1,1,1,1,1]. I tried to find if there's any glitch in the code, but I couldn't. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your initialization of the matrix `M` goes wrong; this is how you can fix it:

```
M = [[0]*5 for i in range(5)]
# this would also work:
# M = [[0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```

the problem is described e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994711/4954037).

short version: all the rows in your matrix point to the same list. a change in one of the rows is reflected in every row.

(btw; `range(0, 5, 1)` is usually just written as `range(5)`)

Comment: To add to hiro's answer, as you already use `numpy`, probably the best way to create `M` would be to directly create an `array` with `M=n.zeros((5,5))`.